# Updating variable through select

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I am very knew to Knockoutjs and I am trying to execute a service call on input select.

I the object looks like this:

```
var teamViewModel = {
    teams: ko.observableArray([]),
    clearTeams: function(){
        this.teams.removeAll();
    },
    addTeam: function (id, name, isChecked) {
        t = new team(id, name, isChecked);
        this.teams.push(t);
    }
};
```

The select box is being populated by calling this:

```
function GetAvailableTeams() {

    var jqxhr =
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/Service.svc/GetTeamsAll',
    function (data) {
        teamViewModel.clearTeams();
        $.each(data.GetTeamsAllResult, 
        function (key, val) {
            teamViewModel.addTeam(val.TeamId, val.TeamName, true);
        });
        ko.applyBindings(teamViewModel, document.getElementById("teamNameLabel"));
    })
}
```

The function is called on pageload and referenced like this:

```
<select id="teamNameLabel" date-theme="f" data-bind="options: teams,  optionsText: 'name', value: 'id'"></select>
```

How do i update the global variable TeamId when an option on the select statement is selected?

EDIT:

```
function GetAllUsersByTeam(){

var url = 'http://localhost/Service.svc/GetUsersByTeam/'+TeamId;

        var jqxhr =
        $.getJSON(url,
        function (data) 
        { 
            colleagueViewModel.clearColleagues();
            $.each(data.GetUsersByTeamResult, function (key, val) {
                colleagueViewModel.addColleague(val.FirstName, val.LastName, val.EmailAddress, val.PhoneNumber, val.LocationName, val.CapabilityId, val.CoeId);
            });
            ko.applyBindings(colleagueViewModel, document.getElementById("colleaguesListView"));
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use a global variable. You can add a `selectedTeam` observable to your view model, that represents the selected option:

```
var teamViewModel = {
    teams: ko.observableArray([]),
    selectedTeam: ko.observable(),
    // ...
}
```

And then, [bind the options'](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) `value` to the `selectedTeam`, that is:

```
<select data-bind="options: teams,  optionsText: 'name', value: selectedTeam">
</select>
```

Finally, to access the `id` of the selected option, simply use `teamViewModel.selectedTeam().id`.

Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7a44n/)**.

Comment: the reason i wanted to use a global variable is because i am calling another function to all members of the team, i will add that function to the original post

Comment: @Mike: I see, but the answer remains the same, but instead of using `TeamId` in your `GetAllUsersByTeam` function use `teamViewModel.selectedTeam().id`, with the advantage that the selected team observable is managed by `ko`.

Comment: Can i initialize the id to 1?

Comment: @Mike: Sure, initialize the `selectedTeam` variable with `ko.observable(1)`.

Comment: fantastic! 2 more questions, how can i get the select to call GetAllUsersByTeam() by just choosing one of the options? and how can i get it so the optionsCaption is the teamViewModel.selectedTeam().name?

Comment: @Mike: You'd need to subscribe to changes to the `selectedTeam`. Here's a small demo http://jsfiddle.net/U7fW9/. There's also a cool ko cart tutorial which also uses this concept http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html.